# The event stop work after html function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, client-side

The Problem is that after the .html() jQuery function, the event for the button is stopped.
Here is an example -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    Create();

    $('body div input').click(function() {
       alert('Hello');
       Create();
    });

    function Create() {
       $('body').html('<div><input type="button" value="button" /></div>');
    }

});
```

Here, the first time I click the button the event is works, but after the Create() function is called again the event won't work anymore.

by the way - The body tag in the html code is blank and it is without any CSS, So it is a jQuery problem.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HVzcy/

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it using the function on() instead of click.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
 $('body').on('click', 'div input', function() {
   alert('Hello');
   Create();
});
```

Comment: The `.live()` method has been deprecated for quite a while now. New code should use `.on()`, which provides the same functionality with a more efficient interface.

Comment: you are right, i have no idea that the live function was deprecated, thanks for the edit :D

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with jQuery, it's a problem with the way you're establishing the event handler.  When you update the contents of a container (the `<body>` in this case), all the previous contents are thrown out, along with any events bound to them.

You can use event delegation at the `<body>` element itself to prevent the handlers from being lost:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div input', function() {
  alert("hello");
});
```

That relies on the fact that browsers (sometimes with jQuery's help) propagate events up the DOM tree. Thus by putting the handler at the `<body>` with that selector to filter events, you'll be able to handle "click" events on any `<input>` elements added to the body at any time.

Comment: Thanks, I did tried the live and on methods and they both worked, but as you said the live has been deprecated, So I use on method then. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

jquery `delegate` can help you in this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   Create();

   $("body").delegate("div input", "click", function(){
      alert('Hello');
      Create();
   });

   function Create() {
      $('body').html('<div><input type="button" value="button" /></div>');
   }​

});
```

you can see it here

http://jsfiddle.net/NjuJ2/1/

Comment: See my comment on @mdaguerre's answer - the `.live()` method has been deprecated for a few years now.